# SFDX - Deploying only components from the last commit

Tags: salesforcedx

I am setting up a CI process using CircleCI, GitHub and SFDX. Developers do their work in a scratch org, then commit their changes to a feature branch and then create a pull request which merges to a QA branch. Upon this commit, the CI pipeline then deploys the components from the last commit (only diff) to a QA sandbox, which is working fine.

The issue is that let's say I am trying to deploy 10 components but it failed due to an error in only 1 component. I correct it, commit it to the feature branch, create a new pull request and merge with QA branch. Now CircleCI fetches only that 1 component which I corrected and committed instead of fetching all the components from the last failed commit. So to be able to deploy all 10 components, I need to do a dummy update (add/remove a space) in the rest of the 9 components so that CircleCI can consider those as modified.

We raised a ticket to CircleCI team but looks like that currently there is no API to retrieve last successful build Id. It may be available in a couple of months atleast.

Is there a way to implement/fix this?

Comment: Maybe the -x flag of force:source:deploy with a commited package.xml file? Then wiping that package.xml after a succesful build... Not ideal but a possible workaround for now

Comment: I would suggest to use the last feature branch and squash and merge so all commits along with new one are taken up or simply reverting the last commit and recommit with changes